# Laravel validation for dynamic form input data?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-validation, dynamicform

Im using **dynamic** form input inserting **array data** but validation for array is not works for me. without input its saving in database as blank values.

In a table column i have inert my form input like this, adding dynamic form field im using vueJs:

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">
 <td>{!! Form::text('description[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','v-model'=>'row.description']) !!}
@if ($errors->has('description'))
       <span class="error"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ $errors->first('description') }}"></i></span>@endIf</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('log_time[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','v-model'=>'row.log_time']) !!}
      @if ($errors->has('log_time'))<span class="error"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ $errors->first('log_time') }}"></i></span>@endIf </td>
<td> <a @click="removeRow(row)"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="dim">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button> </a>
             <a @click="addRow"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="dim">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

My Controller store function :

```
protected $rules = [
        'row.description' => ['required|array'],
        'row.log_time' => ['required|array'],
    ];
public function store(PslCall $call,Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
        $data = array();
        foreach($request->description as $key=>$value){
            $data[]=[
                'description'=> $value,
                'log_time'=> $request->log_time[$key],
                'call_id'=>$call->id,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ];
        }

        PortLog::insert($data);
        return Redirect::route('calls.logs.index',$call->id)->with('message','You have successfully submitted');
    }
```

here you can check my dd() without input i can insert :( for this i have to give validation ;

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "description" => ""
    "log_time" => ""
    "call_id" => 2
    "created_at" => Carbon {#351 ▶}
    "updated_at" => Carbon {#352 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "description" => ""
    "log_time" => ""
    "call_id" => 2
    "created_at" => Carbon {#353 ▶}
    "updated_at" => Carbon {#354 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you assure, `$request` contain all of the values you want to validate?

Comment: @SafoorSafdar check question now

Comment: look like, you need remove `row.` from your validation rules

Comment: ya i removed but its not working

Answer (score 3):

There is issue with your `$rules` Try that

```
protected $rules = [
        'description.*' => 'required|min:1',
        'log_time.*' => 'required|min:1',
    ];
```

Comment: If the description field is an array like, 

    'description' : [ { 'value' : 'testing' } , { 'value' : 'description content'} ]

It can be validated as `description.*` but that's not the case here I think..